# Actualizar una ListBuffer con los valores de otra lista

Tags: scala

¿Cómo puedo actualizar (mas no añadir, o hacer un *append*), elementos de una lista a otra en Scala?

Me encuentra programando en Scala, y trato de actualizar un ListBuffer con los valores que tengo de otra lista:

```scala
val allThemes: ListBuffer[MyType] = ListBuffer[MyType]()

val pageSize = 500
var pageToken = ""

do {
  val response: Response = ...
  val dataThemes: List[MyType] = response.items  // Estos son los nuevos valores
  pageToken = response.next_page_token

  // Aquí tratataba según de actualizar una lista con 
  // nuevos valores
  if (dataThemes.nonEmpty)
    allThemes += dataThemes  // Aquí me da un error de tipo

} while (...)

allThemes.toList
```

Pero me manda un error de tipo porque resulta que no le hace un update como pensé, sino un "append", y por lo tanto los tipos son diferentes.

```
type mismatch; found ListBuffer[List[MyType]] Required: ListBuffer[MyType]
```

Sé que puedo iterar sobre esos valores, y luego hacerles un `+=`, pero no se oye a una opción "elegante", descriptiva.

Comment: Deberías añadir el error que te da. No se puede usar el operador `+=` con objetos inmutables, tal como defines `allThemes`. De todos modos, lo que realmente necesitas es _"concatenar listas"_, algo que hace el operador `++` y similares.

Comment: Me da un error de tipo. Y un `ListBuffer` no es inmutable.

Comment: Añade el error completo para no estar especulando qué error te da. Aunque `ListBuffer` es una colección mutable, `allThemes` es una referencia inmutable por estar declarada como `val allThemes`. No puedes hacer `allThems += ...` ya que equivale a `allThemes = allThemes + ...`, lo que alteraría el valor de la referencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, caso cerrado.

Acabo de leer la documentación oficial, y menciona que se puede hacer eso con un `++=`:

```
lista ++= listaConElementosAanadir
```

[https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html#++=(xs:scala.collection.IterableOnce[A]):Growable.this.type](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html#++=(xs:scala.collection.IterableOnce%5BA%5D):Growable.this.type)

Comment: En dos días la marcaré como la aceptada. A menos que alguien publique una mejor versión